# call .net assembly from delphi (PSafeArray)

Tags: .net, delphi, com

I have assembly written on .net
Here is function from that assembly:

```
public class OMG{
    public Result[] test(){
        var tmp = new List<Result>();
        tmp.Add(new Result(){ var1 = 1, var2 = "test" });
        tmp.Add(new Result(){ var1 = 2, var2 = "test1" });
        return tmp.ToArray();
    }
}
public class Result{
    public int var1;
    public string var2;
}
```

So, i invoke this function from delphi.

```
var
tmp : PSafeArray;

...
tmp:= omg.test();
```

So,here i get PSafeArray, how can i actually retrieve data?

Comment: Have a look at [this article,](http://blog.virtec.org/2008/07/the-mysteries-of-psafearray/) which explains how to get data in and out of a `PSafeArray` in Delphi.